# Can custom slash command be applied to all users of a Mattermost team?

Tags: integration, mattermost

I am in the process of adding some integrations to my Mattermost instance. My team need things like e.g. ability to create hangouts link with one slash command.

However as far as I can see everyone of my team members would have to create the integration by itself. I want to spare them the trouble and set it globally.

Is there some reasonable way to do it or would I have to try to backup my database and then run by hand PostgreSQL queries creating commands for every single team member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Slash Commands in Mattermost are scoped to the team. If one user creates a Custom Slash Command, it will be available to all users in the team where it was created.

However, it will still be owned by the user who has created it. If you have `EnablePostUsernameOverride` set to `true` in your `config.json`, the username of the posts made in response to the Custom Slash Command can be customised. Otherwise, they will have the username of the user who created the Custom Slash Command.